# Getting entityreference field from user

Tags: entities

I created additional field for user profile, which is a reference to node (content type - Company).

How can i get values of this field for a current user?

---

```
 $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());

 $field_company= $user->get('field_company')->value; // result is empty
```

---

I know that second string is wrong, but i don't know what should I write.
Please, help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2055615), this should work:

```
$items = $user->getTranslation($langcode)->get('field_company');
```

Answer (score 0):

For entity reference fields the property containing entity id is `target_id`. So you want to do something like this:

```
$field_company = $user->get('field_company')->target_id;
```

See the [`EntityReferenceFieldItemList`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21EntityReferenceFieldItemList.php/class/EntityReferenceFieldItemList/8) docs for more information on the data available with this field.